# ROW_NUMBER() in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, window-functions, row-number

I want to replicate this in mysql  - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY C) AS X

But I have around 1M records, what would be the most efficient way of achieving it?

I am currently doing the below and it takes forever to execute the query. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT a.A, a.B, a.C, COUNT(*) AS RowNum 
FROM TABLE a
JOIN TABLE b
ON a.A = b.A
AND a.B = b.B
AND a.C >= b.C
GROUP BY a.A, a.B, a.C
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: count(*) makes it load all the records first then count it

Comment: Row_number is available in mysql 8 what version are you on?

Comment: I just updated to mysql 8, but still none of the window functions works, I am getting the below error ( is not valid at this position, expecting EOF,';')

Comment: Please add the query with row_number in it either here or to a fiddle.

Comment: SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY C) AS RowNum FROM Table

Comment: If you get an error from that query then you are not on mysql version 8 , you may be on mysqlworkbench version 8 but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL, the most efficient method is to use variables.  The equivalent of:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY C) AS X
```

would be:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@ab = concat_ws('_', a, b), @rn + 1
                  if(@ab := concat_ws('_', a, b), 1)
                 )
       )
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by a, b, c
     ) t cross join
     (select @ab := '', @rn := 0);
```

If you don't want to use variables, then a correlated subquery is probably the next best method:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b and
              t2.c <= t.c
       ) 
from t;
```

Note:  This is assumes that `c` is unique.  Otherwise the logic is not equivalent.

This can take advantage of an index on `(a, b, c)`, and under many circumstances, the performance will be reasonable.

Why is this better than your method?  Simple:  It avoids the outer aggregation.  Aggregating over the table is likely to be quite expensive, especially after the `JOIN`.